# MySQL C# "Fatal Error Encountered during command execution" error

Tags: c#, mysql

MySQL and C# data update error

```
public static void Guncelleurun(urun urn,string id)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE urunler SET Name = @name, Pricekg = @pricekg WHERE ID=@id";

    MySqlConnection con = GetConnection();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pricekg", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = urn.Pricekg;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.String).Value = urn.Name;

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Güncelleme Başarılı", "Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Güncellenmedi. \n" + ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add parameter @id

like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = urn.Id;
```